# Multiply x-axis by a constant value

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the following Planck Distribution:

```
u[x_, T_] := (8 \[Pi] h )/c^3 x^3/(Exp[h/k x/T] - 1)
Plot[u[x, 2.5*10^9], {x, 0, 10^21}]
```

at 2.5 GK. This works fine however I want to multiply the x-axis by 10^-20. I tried rescaling simply by replacing x with 10^-20x in the function itself and replotting from 0 to 10 but that leads to 1/0 errors as the exponent blows up. Is there a way around this for such big (or small) numbers?

Comment: Try: `Plot[u[10^20 x, 2.5*10^9], {x, 0, 10}]`

Comment: thank you this worked